# opencv error when converting a python file to an .exe file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling, pyinstaller, pyautogui

So I am  trying to convert my python project to an exe file and run it, but when I do, I get an error like this:

**Failed to execute script 'My project' due to unhandled exception: ERROR recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "Myproject.py", line 3, in module  
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module  
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 180, in module  
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 75, in bootstrap  
ImportError:
 ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.
```

Here's some of the code:

```
import pyautogui as pg   
from time import sleep  
import cv2


sleep(1)

pg.hotkey('super', 's')

sleep(0.2)
pg.typewrite('chrome')

sleep(0.3)

pg.press('enter')

sleep(0.4)

pg.typewrite('youtube.com')  
pg.press('enter')
sleep(1)

cords = pg.locateCenterOnScreen('search.png', confidence=0.8)   
pg.click(cords)   
pg.typewrite('a random video')   
pg.press('enter')
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV ? Also.. you import opencv but then you don't use it..

Comment: I installed it from the terminal in vs code using pip install opencv-python, also I just saw that, in order for the confidence argument to work, it needs the cv2 module. That is the only reason I have it there.

Comment: Ok, opencv is necessary.. I didn't know pyautogui. Now.. Is the program working itself or the error is just about the generated exe ?

Comment: Yes, the program works 100% when it runs as a python file. The problem appears when it's converted to exe.

Comment: please try with a clean install of both pyinstaller and opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the problem.I was using the latest 3.10.0 version of Python and apparently, it had some bugs about numpy and opencv modules.

My Advice:

Never use the latest python version. Always the previous one.

Comment: Which version did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling opencv and installing an older version, like version 4.5.3

Comment: Tried installing an older version of it, but unfortunately I am getting a bunch of errors.
but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error.
I got around the error by lowering the python and opencv versions.
I used following versions :

```
Python 3.9.13
opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```

I've tried several combinations, but there seems to be no error.