# Error "ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation." with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller

**Environment:**

Windows 10

PyInstaller: 5.2

Python: 3.10.5

opencv-python 4.6.0.66

**Problem:**

I am trying to compile my Python code with PyInstaller. The exe is created and when I execute it, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PhoneBot.py", line 343, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "modules\prepare_envir_appium.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "modules\mymodulesteam.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI40002\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI40002\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI40002\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI40002\cv2\__init__.py", line 76, in bootstrap
    raise ImportError('ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.')
ImportError: ERROR: recursion is detected during loading of "cv2" binary extensions. Check OpenCV installation.
```

**What did I try:**

- I deactivated my Antivirus.
  It didn't work

I think I tried it all:

- I installed the previous version of OpenCV:

  pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56

It didn't work

- I installed the latest version:

  pip install --upgrade opencv-python
  pip install --upgrade pyinstaller

It didn't work

- I tried to force the reinstallation:

  pip3 install opencv-python --upgrade --force-reinstall

It didn't work

- I added the path of cv2:

  pyinstaller --onefile -F --uac-admin --icon="icon_PhoneBot_256.ico" --clean --noconsole  --collect-data pyshadow --paths="C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\cv2" Project.py

It didn't work

Here are the logs of PyInstaller if it can help:

```
130 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.2
130 INFO: Python: 3.10.5
268 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
269 INFO: wrote C:\Users\gauth\Documents\project\project_debug3\project.spec
275 INFO: UPX is not available.
275 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\pyinstaller
353 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\gauth\\Documents\\project\\project_debug3',
 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2']
1144 INFO: checking Analysis
1144 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1146 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1152 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1162 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'numpy'. Please take care they do not conflict.
1171 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6500 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
6502 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib'
7762 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
7923 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7940 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
8203 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\gauth\Documents\project\project_debug3\project.py
9270 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
13260 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
13262 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
22225 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
32496 INFO: Processing module hooks...
32501 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
32518 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-Cryptodome.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
33041 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
34553 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cv2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
34568 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-google.api_core.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
34571 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-googleapiclient.model.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
34647 WARNING: collect_data_files - skipping data collection for module 'googleapiclient.discovery' as it is not a package.
34648 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-httplib2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
34657 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.etree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
34658 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
35621 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
35622 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-selenium.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
35985 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-unidecode.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
37029 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\_pyinstaller'...
37120 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'f2py'
37133 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37138 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37139 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37144 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37742 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37749 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37806 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37812 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy._pytesttester.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
37818 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
39392 WARNING: Hidden import "jinja2" not found!
39392 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
39494 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
41173 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
41180 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
42001 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
42008 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
42034 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
42044 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
43000 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
43424 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
43425 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
43431 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
43436 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
43663 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
43663 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
43837 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
44120 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
44428 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
44731 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
46244 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
46833 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
46839 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
47606 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
47607 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
47610 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
47611 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
47785 INFO: checking Tree
47785 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
47787 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
47929 INFO: checking Tree
47930 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
47932 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
48034 INFO: checking Tree
48034 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
48036 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
48043 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.isoschematron.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
48053 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lxml.objectify.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
48054 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
48631 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
49207 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
49737 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
49837 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
50085 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
50106 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
50113 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
50120 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32api.py'
50121 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
50123 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
50126 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
50130 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
50133 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\gauth\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_subprocess.py'
50162 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py:156: UserWarning: The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.
  __import__(package)
54020 INFO: Looking for eggs
54021 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll
54023 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
54041 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\gauth\Documents\project\project_debug3\build\project\warn-project.txt
54297 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\gauth\Documents\project\project_debug3\build\project\xref-project.html
54366 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
54373 INFO: checking PYZ
54373 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
54375 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\gauth\Documents\project\project_debug3\build\project\PYZ-00.pyz
56527 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\gauth\Documents\project\project_debug3\build\project\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
56577 INFO: checking PKG
56578 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
56580 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) project.pkg
86615 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) project.pkg completed successfully.
86640 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
86640 INFO: checking EXE
86640 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
86641 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
86643 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\gauth\Documents\project\project_debug3\dist\project.exe.notanexecutable
86648 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
86653 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\gauth\\Documents\\project\\project_debug3\\icon_project_256.ico']
86654 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 20 bytes
86654 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 14739 bytes
86657 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
86657 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
86659 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\gauth\Documents\project\project_debug3\dist\project.exe.notanexecutable
86660 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
86663 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
86763 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
87437 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Is there anyone who has any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes, I do. Why?

Comment: 1rst) I can't share the full code. 2nd) I think it is environmental problem. Not the code. So it would be useless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011937/opencv-error-when-converting-a-python-file-to-an-exe-file-with-pyinstaller Try python==4.9.13 and opencv==4.5.3.56

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011937/opencv-error-when-converting-a-python-file-to-an-exe-file-with-pyinstaller Try Python 3.9.13 with opencv-python==4.5.3.56

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the issues has been resolved, can check here if anyone faces same issues [Github Pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6964)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved by changing the OpenCV version
Exactly from version 4.6.0.66 to 4.5.5.64